# How to access SMB shares from Sony Bravia internet TV?

Tags: sony, smb, television

Is there a way to access content shared by SMB servers, from a Sony Bravia internet TV.
The TV currently supports accessing Videos/Music/Pictures from a DLNA server. I want to know if there is a way to access SMB shares on LAN.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think that Sony Bravia support SMB shares. However you can install a Media Server like MiniDLNA, Serviio, Plex, TVMobili etc... and then share these files over DLNA. As many of these Media Servers can access remote SMB shares so you can install a media server on you Mac / Windows / Linux and then expose the SMB share using media server to your Sony Bravia.

Hope it helps.

Comment: I know for a fact that my SONY Bravia TV discovers a Windows notebook shared folders. However, I can't seem to get it to recognize SAMBA shares running on my Arch Linux notebook. I don't know why it doesn't get along with SAMBA but all the other apps like ES FileExplorer, Archos Video Player and so on work with this server very well. It's the stock Android applications (Video, etc.) that don't work.